# What is causing this SQL/Hibernate error in JBoss 7.1.1?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, maven, jboss

We have an application which works fine in our first environment, but fails in the new environment. Everything, that we can see, is the same. We have given the MySQL user complete access across all hosts, but we still get this 'access denied' error.

The stack trace is pasted below. The main difference, is that our MySQL server on our first environment is 5.6 CE, while on our new environment, it is 5.6 Enterprise Edition.

I am absolutely stuck. I have tried changing the builds to include newer connectors, to no avail.

```
11:24:52,138 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/dealer]] (MSC service thread 1-2) Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class com.apptest.web.LuceneIndexListener: javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Access denied for user 'apptestuser'@'xx.xx.xx.xx' (using password: YES)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.handleExceptionInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:166) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:230) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:304) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:190) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:59) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:32) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.TCCLInterceptor.processInvocation(TCCLInterceptor.java:45) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:165) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$1.processInvocation(ViewDescription.java:173) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:72) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at com.apptest.dealer.ejb3.DealerSearch$$$view7.findAllDealers(Unknown Source) [apptest-services.jar:]
    at com.apptest.web.LuceneIndexListener.reindexDealer(LuceneIndexListener.java:47) [classes:]
    at com.apptest.web.LuceneIndexListener.contextInitialized(LuceneIndexListener.java:40) [classes:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3392) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3850) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:90) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_17]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_17]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_17]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Access denied for user 'apptestuser'@'xx.xx.xx.xx' (using password: YES)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1361) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1289) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:261) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at com.apptest.dealer.ejb3.DealerSearchImpl.findAllDealers(DealerSearchImpl.java:60) [apptest-services.jar:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_17]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_17]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_17]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) [rt.jar:1.7.0_17]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptorFactory$ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptorFactory.java:72) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:36) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.SBInvocationInterceptor.processInvocation(SBInvocationInterceptor.java:47) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:21) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.pool.PooledInstanceInterceptor.processInvocation(PooledInstanceInterceptor.java:51) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:228) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    ... 30 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Access denied for user 'apptestuser'@'xx.xx.xx.xx' (using password: YES)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:52) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractStatementProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractStatementProxyHandler.java:129) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractProxyHandler.invoke(AbstractProxyHandler.java:81) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy77.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1978) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:829) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:289) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2463) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2449) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2279) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2274) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:470) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:355) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:196) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1115) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:101) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:252) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    ... 50 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'apptestuser'@'xx.xx.xx.xx' (using password: YES)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1078) [mysql-connector-java-5.1.25.jar:]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4187) [mysql-connector-java-5.1.25.jar:]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4119) [mysql-connector-java-5.1.25.jar:]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2570) [mysql-connector-java-5.1.25.jar:]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2731) [mysql-connector-java-5.1.25.jar:]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2815) [mysql-connector-java-5.1.25.jar:]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2155) [mysql-connector-java-5.1.25.jar:]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2322) [mysql-connector-java-5.1.25.jar:]
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.CachedPreparedStatement.executeQuery(CachedPreparedStatement.java:107)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedPreparedStatement.executeQuery(WrappedPreparedStatement.java:462)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_17]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_17]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_17]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) [rt.jar:1.7.0_17]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractStatementProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractStatementProxyHandler.java:122) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    ... 65 more
```

Comment: It is probably a permissions problem database user. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/access-denied.html

Comment: Federico: As I stated already, we gave the user all the permissions they could possibly get. Some queries run, but this stack seems to fail for whatever reason

Comment: How do you access to database? datasource?

Comment: jdbc, you can see it in the stack trace

Comment: Yes, I see you are using jpa/hibernate. All application uses the same persistence unit?

Answer (score 1):

i am guessing even though the "user" has access to the database, they need permission to access it from the new environment's ip address.  ensure that the GRANT for that user includes the new hosts name or ip address in the GRANT.

Comment: We added the user as user@% - they also had every permission humanly possible

Comment: have you tested if the host in question can connect to the mysql instance?  try connecting from the command line using the mysql client as the user in question.

Comment: also is the stacktrace virgin or did you edit the ip address in the exception report.  if the ST is "clean", then the ip address of the mysql host is not set properly in your jboss instance configuration ('xx.xx.xx.xx' rather than '123.45.67.89')